# Return row data based on Distinct Column value

Tags: sql, t-sql, asp-classic, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using SQL Azure with asp script, and for the life of me, have had no luck trying to get this to work. The table I'm running a query on has many columns, but I want to query for distinct values on 2 columns (name and email), from there I want it to return the entire row's values.

What my query looks like now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT quote_contact, quote_con_email 
FROM quote_headers 
WHERE quote_contact LIKE '"&query&"%'
```

But I need it to return the whole row so I can retrieve other data points. Had I been smart a year ago, I would have created a separate table just for the contacts, but that's a year ago.

And before I implemented LiveSearch features.

Comment: But if you have five rows that have the same name and same e-mail - which of the five rows do you want to show?? You can't really squeeze data from five rows into one ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression). With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `quote_contact` and `quote_con_email` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those partitions, ordered by some other criteria - i.e. probably `SomeDateTimeStamp`.

So try something like this:

```
;WITH DistinctContacts AS
(
   SELECT 
       quote_contact, quote_con_email, (other columns here),
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY quote_contact, quote_con_email ORDER BY SomeDateTimeStamp DESC) 
   FROM 
       dbo.quote_headers
   WHERE
       quote_contact LIKE '"&query&"%'
)
SELECT 
   quote_contact, quote_con_email, (other columns here)
FROM 
   DistinctContacts
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
```

Here, I am selecting only the last entry for each "partition" (i.e. for each pair of name/email) - ordered in a descending fashion by the time stamp.

Does that approach what you're looking for??

Comment: Marc, this approach sounds like what I'm looking for. I will have to give it a try shortly.

Comment: After some tinkering with it, I was able to get to work well. The query reduced the number of results down to mostly bad miss types from past headers, otherwise, works well.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details.
This is what I could come up with Without them:

```
WITH dist as (
SELECT DISTINCT quote_contact, quote_con_email, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY quote_contact, quote_con_email) rankID
FROM quote_headers 
WHERE quote_contact LIKE '"&query&"%'
),
data as (
SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY quote_contact, quote_con_email) rankID FROM quote_headers 
)
SELECT * FROM dist d INNER JOIN data src ON d.rankID = src.rankID
```